# Data synchronization between redundant nodes vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, distributed, data-synchronization, redundancy

I have a simple class;

```
public class Person
    public property Name as string
    public property CurrentLocation as integer
    public property LastSeen as Datetime
end class
```

And these persons are in a list

```
Public AllPersons are list(of Person)
```

My software runs on 1 to 20 nodes in the network. This data needs to be synced throughout the 20 nodes, without depending on one node to sync. These nodes need to be redundant, meaning the sync process should continue even if 18 random nodes are not available any more. Every node already has a complete list of every other node. The node can reach other nodes on the same lan using a TCP connection. Preferred method of communication is using the Nancy framework. It's a simple list of 100 to maybe 50000 users, containing maybe, up to 10 properties each. All very small, like datetime format, integer or string.

So distributed/decentralized is key here, also high frequency syncing with little data is required. There can be up to 25-50 changes within a minute, only containing maximum of 100 bytes of data.

The purpose is redundancy, the service is behind a loadbalancer and every node should have the same data set, without creating a single point of failure. Creating a back-end database is not and option, because this will introduce a new requirement and a single point of failure. As the tag's indicate, I'm looking for a Windows/.NET solution.

Is there a existing solution I can use?, if not, is there documentation on how to approach this?

Comment: I can think of many solutions but without knowing more about your requirements and constraints, it is difficult to suggest something. The only constraint you specify is that the nodes are on the same LAN. Can they share disks, what are the rules to synch them? Knowing the purpose behind the synch process could also be helpful.

Comment: Robert, I've edited my original question to hopefully answer your questions. Sharing disks is not the preferred way of communicating. A TCP connection is, using the Nancy framework.

Comment: Where do updates come from, what CAP model are you looking for? Nancy isn't a communication method. What is your update rate? How is data dependant on each other, can it be easily partitioned? What access guarantee do you need? How does your model versioning work/upgrading your network code? How high is the required availablity? In other words, your question is anything but simple.

Comment: You can use [Redis](https://redis.io/).

Comment: Thanks RobertBaron, I'm looking into this now; https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/

Comment: It seems, Redis does not fit my description. I've asked for a server-less windows solution. Redis requires a linux server.

Comment: @Aron asked good questions that you have not really answered. If updates are actually originating from every node, then each node could simply broadcast (UDP) updates on the nodes (sub)network.Then each node will simply listen for broadcasted updates and update its copy of the data.

Comment: My question is anything from simple. The more I try to find a solution, the more other troubles I find. The update rate is in the question. CAP model?, I don't know what that is. The data is easily partinioned, the latest update for a user, can override every earlier record of that user. I'm asking how a model should work, you're asking my question back. How high: high as can be.

Comment: You seriously have to answer each of my questions before we can say what solution works for you. If you can't answer my question, you have no right to even attempt to write your own solution.

Comment: CAP is the first question you need to answer if you want distributed data, it sounds like you want Availability and Parity. Try CouchDB. You can also look at ravendb.

Comment: CAP is abbreviation for capacity, I believe.

Comment: I think I've given a estimation of the capacity, 25 to 50 changes per minute. Max 5000 users

Comment: See [Sending and receiving UDP packets in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695669/sending-and-receiving-udp-packets-in-net) for an UDP implementation. Whenever a node has a change, it broadcasts it to all other nodes that are listening. That will be fast, more than what you need, and relatively simple to implement.

Comment: I've ended up using Raft.net it needs custom implementation